# Implementing custom Searcher in vespa

Tags: bigdata, vespa

I have created Basic search application in Vespa with an implementation of the Searcher class. I have fed these below documents using my application one by one.

```json
{
    "fields": {
        "album": "Good",
        "artist": "Arijit",
        "title": "tum ho",
        "year": 2017,
        "duration": 300
    }
}
{
    "fields": {
        "album": "Good",
        "artist": "Atif",
        "title": "bewajah",
        "year": 2017,
        "duration": 300
    }
}
{
    "fields": {
        "album": "bad",
        "artist": "Neha",
        "title": "tere",
        "year": 2017,
        "duration": 400
    }
}
```

My Searcher class is below:

```java
public class ExampleSearcher extends Searcher {

    @Override
    public Result search(Query query, Execution execution) {

        retrun execution.search(query); 
    }
}
```

Now when I search using the API:

```
http://localhost:8080/search/?album=good OR http://localhost:8080/search/?=good
```

I got the result:

```json
{
    "root": {
        "id": "toplevel",
        "relevance": 1,
        "fields": {
            "totalCount": 0
        }
    }
}
```

But I should get this result output:

```json
{
    "root": {
        "id": "toplevel",
        "relevance": 1,
        "fields": {
            "totalCount": 2
        },
        "children": [{
            "id": "good",
            "relevance": 1,
            "fields": {
                "album": "Good",
                "artist": "Arijit",
                "title": "tum ho",
                "year": 2017,
                "duration": 300
            }
        }, {
            "id": "good",
            "relevance": 1,
            "fields": {
                "album": "Good",
                "artist": "Atif",
                "title": "bewajah",
                "year": 2017,
                "duration": 300
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong or how should I do it?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/search-api.html ? The syntax is /search/?query=good

Comment: Or do /search/?query=album:good if you want to limit on that field.

Comment: Yes, I have also used the same but the same result with totalCount 0.**Any other idea?**

Comment: Same result @FrodeLundgren

Comment: Could you provide your exact document definition and services.xml file? Also you can get a trace of the execution by adding &tracelevel=9 to the request.

Comment: My Service.xml -------->?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<services version="1.0">

    <container id="default" version="1.0">
        <document-api/>
        <search>
            <chain id="default">
                <searcher id="com.mydomain.example.ExampleSearcher" bundle="basic-search-java"/>
            </chain>
        </search>
        <nodes>
            <node hostalias="node1"/>
        </nodes>
    </container>
...

</services> Not able to add whole xml

Comment: Not able to add whole response here after exexcution of http://localhost:8080/search/?query=good&tracelevel=9.

Comment: * *Service.xml*  -> https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps/blob/master/basic-search-java/src/main/application/services.xml
* *Document definition* * -> https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps/blob/master/basic-search-java/src/main/application/searchdefinitions/music.sd

Comment: To actually search the content node instead of just mocking a Hello world result as in the example you'll need to add to your chain 'inherits=vespa' to https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps/blob/master/basic-search-java/src/main/application/services.xml#L8

Comment: Thanks @JoKristianBergum Its works.wooo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually search the content node(s) instead of just mocking a Hello world result as in the example you'll need to add to your chain 'inherits=vespa' to the search chain configuration in services.xml.

Comment: Thanks  @JoKristianBergum. its working now.And, Please upvote this question.